# OpenCV NAO error read()

Tags: python, opencv, camera, nao-robot

I put the following python code in the NAO robot to capture and get the frame from one if its camera.

```
import cv2
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame = cap.read()   #This is where the error takes place
```

the program returns

```
VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
```

Comment: might be a hardware / driver issue...

Comment: Your webcam is not capturing. Could be dozens of reasons for that. I think you should use the naoqi instead of cv2.VideoCapture to get a camera feed.

Comment: I was using naoqi, but my plan was to stream the frame, but I dont know how to convert from QImage to Numpy, the one that uses openCV, to handle the image in a server

Comment: convert to numpy is "quite simple":  dataImage = self.avd.getImageRemote( self.strMyClientName )

            if( dataImage != None ):
                  Image = (
                           numpy.reshape(
                                 numpy.frombuffer(dataImage[6], dtype='%iuint8' % dataImage[2]), 
                                 (dataImage[1], dataImage[0], dataImage[2])
                                        )
                          )
              return image

Comment: Or have a look there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGj3H6ETHJg (presentation are in comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, I used pyQt, the instructions are in the NAO's official page, and then convert QImage to OpenCV, the solution can be founded in google.